# Upgrade MVC1/xVal project to MVC2 and compatibilities with client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, xval, client-side-validation

I am currently looking here to migrate a project from MVC1 to MVC2. We are using xVal for client side validation.

From what I understand, I only have to remove references to xVal and replace by MVC2 EnableClientSideValidation and it should do the trick. Anything else would be required ?

Also, with xVal could not validate on client side a list of models, is it still the case with MVC2 + ClientSideValidation ? (what I mean with the "list of models" is doing validation on a `List<TypeOfModel>`)

Example of this is :
controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.Model1 model = new Models.Model1();
        model.Usernames = new List<Models.Model2>();

        model.Usernames.Add(new Models.Model2 {  });
        model.Usernames.Add(new Models.Model2 {  });
        model.Usernames.Add(new Models.Model2 {  });
        model.Usernames.Add(new Models.Model2 {  });

        return View(model);
    }
```

Model1:

```
class Model1 {  
public List<Model2> Usernames { get; set; }
}
```

Model2:

```
class Model2 {  
[Required]
public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %> 

        <% foreach (var username in Model.Usernames) { %> 
            <% Html.RenderPartial("View2", username); %>
            <br /><br />
        <% } %>

        <input type="submit" />

    <% } %>
```

View2:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(f => f.Username) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Username)%>
```

This is a POC where MVC2 client side validation is failing since it validates by field id...

Comment: You are right about removing xVal references. I guess that should be it. I am not sure about your second scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been there, done that, got the T-Shirt. And wish I never went there -- MVC2 validation is frankly not on par with xVal once you've got xVal properly implemented. In addition, MVC3 validation is much, much better done. So, if I were jumping off xVal, I would vector towards making it work with MVC3 which is a much different beast.

Comment: Knowing that MVC3 is only RC is unfortunately not an option for us there as we need rock solid stable dev. Tho maybe you could point me to useful resources to make the transition from MVC1 to MVC2 to MVC3 as painless as possible ?

Comment: I feel ya -- and that was my mistake for the first 2 revisions of the MVC stack. If it is in RC stage it is probably what you should be building against.

Answer (score 0):

Though I subscribe somewhat to what Wyatt said here especially the part about MVC3, but I have been using MVC2 client side validation and it has not been a bad experience at all.

To answer your question, you need to do the following:
1. Include MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js in your view.
2. Then simply call the helper <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

It should pickup your DataAnnotation model validation rules and give you client side validation without much effort.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify the problem ... client side validation does not validate each fields